# How long will a Logic App continue to check a HTTP 202 Accepted response?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

How long will a Logic App continue to check a HTTP 202 Accepted response?

With the "Asynchronous Pattern" setting enabled, calling an endpoint that continues to return a HTTP 202 with a valid "location" header

Will the logic app just carry on for ever ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will depend upon the combination of the asynchronous pattern flag and the time out specified on the HTTP action. Consider following scenarios

I have a long running orchestration which basically has a delay of 5 min before echoing back the received message. Notice in the image below that I have set the aysnchronous flag to true hence the logic app returns a 202.

[image: Long Running Logic App]

Now in my calling logic app, I am calling above long running logic app with following settings on my the HTTP action.
[image: HTTP Action to call the Long running process]

This setting will cause the Logic app to time out after polling the long running logic app for 1 minute. 
I have added a status code of 500 to be sent out if the HTTP actions fails or times out.

[image: Send 500 after time out]

Following is the request I made it returned a status of 202

[image]

When I did a GET on the url received in above call after 1 minute I received a 500 Status code

[image]

Following is the Logic app run history, which shows that the Logic App stopped waiting after 1 Minutes of polling

[image]

Now I have removed the Timeout defined previously and made a request as shown below
[image]

After 5 minutes I have received a response as Logic app has reached a terminal state.
[image]

The logic app history proves that the logic app took 5 minutes to complete

[image]