# Logic Apps - HTTP Core - success with 202 status and asynchronous pattern

Tags: api, azure-logic-apps

Here is my LogicApp:

[image: App]

It is calling API which launches process running for 10 minutes, returns 202 and returns location header for status checks and when is done it returns 200. I have asynchronous pattern enabled and time limit set to PT2H in this Logic app. So I expect it to run for about 10 minutes periodically checking status until 200 is received or time out.
However, in overview tab this app shows successful run with duration of 1.09 seconds.

This is a bit counterintuitive. What am I missing?

To check the setup, I updated my API to return status 400 upon completion and my LogicApp is supposed to send email in case of error or time out. API ran fine and returned 400 status, but I did not get an e-mail, so I do nothing polling is happening correct. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I do repro in my lab after creating a ISE for logic app by using as follows with duration of 5 mins. And after 5 min. received mail as well.

Going to  Logic App designer and created with Recurrence Core.
[image]

Added scheduler> Delay  for the time to hold for http core in delay section as follows:
[image]

[image]

Then added HTTP core> settings> Asynchronus pattern ON and Timeout set as below:
[image]

And set same setting for the send email as well from the setting.
[image: ![enter image description here]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuEdz.png)

And after that we can save it and run the Logic app . Then We can check the overview as per delay time which i set earlier:
[image]

For further information please refer the [How Long will aLogic App Continue to check a HTTP 202 Accepted Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60652270/how-long-will-a-logic-app-continue-to-check-a-http-202-accepted-response)  and the [Doc](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/calling-long-running-functions-from-logic-apps-6d7ba5044701).